# different versions for the same controller action rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, version

I have a action something like:

```
def show
    @p = Post.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
```

I get a url something:

```
http://localhost:3000/post/1
http://localhost:3000/post/2
http://localhost:3000/post/3
.
.
.
```

**I want have a different version for this same action something like:**

```
http://localhost:3000/v1/post/1
http://localhost:3000/v1/post/2
http://localhost:3000/v1/post/3
.
.
.
```

**How can I do it?**

I have take a look to this resources:

https://github.com/bploetz/versionist

http://railscasts.com/episodes/350-rest-api-versioning?view=asciicast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the straight forward way would be to use namespacing, e.g. V1::PostsController, V2::PostsController, etc.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

However, if you're just producing an API, then you should better use https://github.com/intridea/grape , as it has the versioning support baked in.

Answer (score 0):

In your routes file you could add something like

`map '/v1/post/:id' => 'yourcontroller#show'`

That would be in addition to your existing `resources :post` or whatever.